# data-transition not working

Tags: ajax, listview, jquery-mobile

i have a listview in an ajax. i want to add data-transition to this link. i tried to add

```
data-transition="slide"
```

in the code. but there's nothing change. but i tried to used this code in normal  in html, the data-transition works but not with page that have ajax there. same goes when i tried

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "flip";
```

page with no ajax works well but not for page with ajax. example of my ajax is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $('#MregisteredClasses').on('pageinit', function(){
                var rowInput = "1";
                var pageInput = "1";

                $.ajax({
                 url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getRegisteredClassesData.html',
                 data: ( {rows : rowInput , page : pageInput}),
                 type: 'POST',

                success: function(json_results){
                    $('#list').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="gear" data-transition="slide"</ul>');
                    listItems = $('#list').find('ul');
                    $.each(json_results.rows, function(key) {
                      html = "<li <h3><a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MRegisteredClassesDetail.phone?courseId=" 
                             + [json_results.rows[key].courseId] + "&regNo=" + [json_results.rows[key].regNo] +
                             "' data-transition='slide' rel='external'>" + json_results.rows[key].courseName+ "</a></h3>"
                             + "<a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MRateCourse.phone?courseId=" 
                             + [json_results.rows[key].courseId] + "&regNo=" + [json_results.rows[key].regNo] + 
                             "' data-transition='slide' rel='external'>RATE THIS COURSE</a>" ;
                    listItems.append(html); 
                    });

                $('#list ul').listview(); 
                },
            });
            });
        </script>
```

anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Where are you seeing this behavior?  Does it work if you run it on Chrome?

Comment: nope..i tried already in chrome.. i don't know whats the prob

Answer (score 0):

i know why it does not come out, we can't use data-transition and data-ajax/rel=external together as data-ajax/rel=external load the full page again so transition is not possible..